# How extend Windows 8 Explorer Ribbon with custom controls?

Tags: c#, windows-8, explorer, extend

As example, I want make simple resizer, where you can select image in explorer and set new dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the Windows Explorer 8 ribbon.

> However, add-ins will not be able to plug into the ribbon UI. This was
>   a difficult engineering choice for us and we expect that many of you
>   will read this and suggest we add the capability--of course if we
>   could get it right this time around we would have done that. A big
>   part of this blog is sharing these choices--tradeoffs--between new
>   features and adding everything we can dream up and finishing.  We also
>   think the customization we provide and the improvements are worthwhile
>   this time around.

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/08/29/improvements-in-windows-explorer.aspx).

Comment: What about Windows 10?

Comment: @deed02392 I haven't found anything indicating its changed.