# Is it possible to write a shell extensions that add a button in the windows file explorer?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-shell

Is it possible to write a shell extension that adds a button in the windows file explorer?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580362/how-extend-windows-8-explorer-ribbon-with-custom-controls

Comment: This is a UI Ribbon (from the Windows Ribbon Framework) loaded by explorer frame. Its layout is completely hardcoded in the ribbon UI definition (this is how the  ribbon framework works in fact) built in explorer frame binary. Even the contextual tab that can appear sometimes (when you select a video or an image, etc. along Home Share and View) is hardcoded in the explorer's ribbon definition. It (only one at a time) appears depending on the type of shell folder or item.